# change text in label of CRM chart

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have a chart in CRM

It is for a field called isQualified with **Yes** and **No** as possible values

Now in the chart I want to change the lable of Yes, No to **Qualified and Not Qualified**

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: I believe you are going to have to change your "Two Option" value labels (from Yes to Qualified and No to Not Qualified) in the respective field definition.

Comment: if there is no other way, can you post this as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: I've added my comments as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the axis display values, you will have to change the display text of the respective "Two Option" selections in the field properties.

1. Go to the Customize options of the respective entity.
2. Under the Fields listing, edit the properties.
3. Update the display labels appropriate and then publish your changes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, the labels you want change would be the series labels and series labels are dynamically created based on the data source. The only way you could change them would be if you had access to chart event handlers, which CRM does not provide. The best you can do is change the colors, hide the labels altogether by editing the [Chart's Data Description XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309699.aspx).

If this chart would go on a dashboard, an alternative would be to use a web resource and use a client side library like [ChartJs](http://www.chartjs.org/) and build your chart. The chart looks fairly simple, resurfacing it using JavaScript should not be too complicated.

Comment: Upvoted, Thanks 

I am trying to do it with out of the box functionalities, which seems to be impossible

Comment: Good technical explanation. I would add as an alternate that you can do this in an SSRS report as well (if you are on-premise).